# Php MySQLi Undefined values(variables)

Tags: php

Okay so I fixed my mistake but I am still getting an error. I am not use to MySQLi but I would like to help my friend get something working for his site he is making.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$firstname = filter($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = filter($_POST['lastname']);
$age = filter($_POST['age']);
}

$db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
    if ($db->connect_error) {
            $message = $db->connect_error;
            die($message);
    }


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($db->error) {
            $message = $db->error;
            die($message);
    }

    $db->query("INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,age)
    VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$age."')");

    mysqli_close($db);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="confirmation.php" method="POST">
First Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
Last Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="lastname" />
Age:<br />
<input type="text" name="age"  />
Submit:<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error we are getting ->

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: firstname in C:\wamp\www\website\register.php on line 25
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 244952 {main}( ) ..\register.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: lastname in C:\wamp\www\website\register.php on line 25
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 244952 {main}( ) ..\register.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: age in C:\wamp\www\website\register.php on line 25
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 244952 {main}( ) ..\register.php:0
```

When I do this in the old MySQL I don't get no such error like this so I am very confused since it is working for me when I do it but with the SQLi I get the error.

Comment: You're running your query before you assign the values to your variables. This is both obvious and something that doesn't work no matter what API you use.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I missed that yes I see why it wouldn't work at all, thank you John for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you show what `filter()` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code block needs to be first, before any MySQL query attempt.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = filter($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = filter($_POST['lastname']);
    $age = filter($_POST['age']);
}
```

This code block defines the variables used. In your current example, the variables aren't set until after the query attempt - that's why you're getting the error.

Thus:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = filter($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = filter($_POST['lastname']);
    $age = filter($_POST['age']);
    $db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
    if ($db->connect_error) {
            $message = $db->connect_error;
            die($message);
    }


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($db->error) {
            $message = $db->error;
            die($message);
    }

    $db->query("INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,age)
     VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$age."')");

    mysqli_close($db);
}

?>
```

Comment: That's still an error as you're always running the query whether the values are set or not

Comment: Yeah I am still getting the error I updated my post or question I hope it helps on explain my error I am getting, its the Value() part

Comment: Please see the updated code block from @Sphinxxx - his if() statement properly encapsulates the rest of the query code, so the query is not attempted unless this is a $_POST form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the fields actually have data in them.

```
$required = array(
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'age'
);

$missing = array();
foreach($required as $item) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$item}) || empty($_POST[$item])) {
        $missing[] = $item;
    }
}

if(!empty($missing)) {
    die("You need to supply the required fields. (" .implode(", ", $missing). ")");
} else {
    // run the query here.
}
```

As you can see, we run the `$required` array to ensure the values are set in the `$_POST` superglobal and are **not** empty. As we require them to run this.

I still, however think your `filter()` function has something to do. Could you supply that?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$firstname = filter($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = filter($_POST['lastname']);
$age = filter($_POST['age']);


$db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
    if ($db->connect_error) {
            $message = $db->connect_error;
            die($message);
    }


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($db->error) {
            $message = $db->error;
            die($message);
    }

    $db->query("INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,age)
     VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$age."')");

    mysqli_close($db);
}
else { die("No post data was submitted");  }
?>
```